# Is it possible to track a variable back to its extract() function?

Tags: php, drupal

I am working with a Drupal theme, and I see a lot of variables which look like were created with `extract()`. Is it possible to track back, and see where that array is?

Comment: If I understood your question, you want to see the place in code where the variable is declared. Whatever the IDE you are using, there should be a "go to declaration" or "go to definition" option when you right-click the variable name.

Comment: extract() should be taken out back and tortured to death, then drawn, quartered, and buried face down beside the corpses of register_globals and magic_quotes

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: If the variable was "declared" using `extract`, that won't work.  For example: `$array = getValues();  extract($array);  echo $b;`  `$b` came from the `$array` variable, there's no way for the IDE to know this.

Comment: lol marc, another function i'd like to see buried is header("Location") , maybe not a function but header needs to be completely redone. i hate how any white space, html or anything related before the header function trows that annoying error. why is php the only one that does it this way.

Comment: Sarmen B: That's inherent to the way HTTP headers work. They can't come after data -- otherwise they wouldn't exactly be "headers"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo the `$GLOBALS` variable and you might find where it came from if the array was **not** unset.

Answer (score 2):

I take you are referring to the variables passed to a template file, which effectively are extracted from an array.

The code that does that in Drupal 7 is in [theme_render_template()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_render_template/7).

```
function theme_render_template($template_file, $variables) {
  extract($variables, EXTR_SKIP); // Extract the variables to a local namespace
  ob_start(); // Start output buffering
  include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $template_file; // Include the template file
  return ob_get_clean(); // End buffering and return its contents
}
```

The function is called from [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7), which executes the following code.

```
// Render the output using the template file.
$template_file = $info['template'] . $extension;
if (isset($info['path'])) {
  $template_file = $info['path'] . '/' . $template_file;
}
$output = $render_function($template_file, $variables);
```

`$render_function` by default is set to `'theme_render_template'`, but its value is set with the following code (in `theme()`).

```
// The theme engine may use a different extension and a different renderer.
global $theme_engine;
if (isset($theme_engine)) {
  if ($info['type'] != 'module') {
    if (function_exists($theme_engine . '_render_template')) {
      $render_function = $theme_engine . '_render_template';
    }
    $extension_function = $theme_engine . '_extension';
    if (function_exists($extension_function)) {
      $extension = $extension_function();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with Drupal so this is just a suggestion, but if drupal has a templating structure or if an array is passed from a controller or such then possible that extract is used,
You could use `get_defined_vars` within your view to get all vars and its possible that there is an array there that you can cross reference with variables you know of that are in the same array or such.

```
<?php 
$vars = get_defined_vars();
print_r($vars);
//or maybe
print_r($this);
?>
```

Comment: thnx , thats what i had done and through reading through all the lines i eventually found what declared it.

Comment: glad it helped, debugging bloated scripts can be a pain sometimes